# LaTeX "Powerpoint with animation"

Tags: presentations

Recently, I watched this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smEyHuQrBvg

It is quite a nice program with latex generated seemingly on-the-fly, and working like some kind of "Powerpoint presentation".

Does anyone know what program it is?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is better to post a question that the reader does not have to leave TeX.SX to understand...but I guess that this is hard to do here:)

Comment: I guess that is Beamer PDF showed with a special presentation tool as [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net). May be with the help of a script (for example a .info file made by `impressive-gettransitions`). I think that at least some effects  (e.g., pointer traced red lines) are not (or cannot be simulated) with these tools, but I have very little experience with this program.

Comment: Judging by the `Typesetting math` box that pops up in the lower left corner from time to time, that is displayed by MathJax in a browser.

Comment: There's zero reason to expect TeX or LaTeX to be involved here, and the obvious way to find out how it's done is to ask the author. To me, that makes this off-topic: I don't see what we can give as an answer.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if something like this can be done with latex, for example using some incremental typesetting and `animate`.

Comment: [A comment on video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smEyHuQrBvg&lc=z13rjpa5rkipevee5221vhaiptjpfhual04.1411858599732922) posted asked about this; it is something the makers made themselves.